This issue wasn’t resolved; there were some color issues for the moderator tags in “Network Profile”
I found that a staff marked my previous question (Some tags in “Top Questions” in “Network Profile” have different colors for their font as in Meta Stack Exchange) as status-completed 3 hours ago. The staff didn’t write any answers or reply me.

But, when I see my network profile, I still found that the colors for the moderator tag status-completed in “Top Questions” in “Network Profile” have different colors as in Meta Stack Exchange.

In network profile, the status-completed tag wasn’t in orange color like in the Meta Stack Exchange. The moderator status-completed tag in the network profile have the same color like the required tag and normal tag.

So, I would want to report this unsolved bug again in Meta Stack Exchange.

I guess the actual question is: has it been working before? Which could change this to [tag:feature-request] instead of [tag:bug].

@MetaAndrewT. I can’t make sure for this, the color and font of the tags have been changed recently.

The staff marked several bugs as completed in a batch, so perhaps that one was done by mistake. I've posted a comment asking to clarify, or remove the wrong tag, if removed you can delete this one here.

Another option is that it was meant to be declined, which is fair, and in this case as @MetaAndrewT said, you can ask to reverse the decision but only if giving some new reasoning, otherwise it would still be the same request.

There was no separate colouring for moderator-only and/or required tags on that page before: https://web.archive.org/web/20240303024633/https://stackexchange.com/users/6085540/glorfindel

@Glorfindel ah, but the tag is still wrong, should be [tag:status-bydesign] and better also explain in an answer, really not trivial to know that.
